# Using localize resource with ViewBag variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, localization, resources

I have the following code in my page:

```
 @{ foreach (var cat in ViewBag.Categories)
    {
        <div class="swiper-slide">@cat.CateName</div>

    }
  }
```

cat variable contains two properties `CateName` and `CateNameLocalized`.

As I'm using localization in my project, how to get the right property based on current culture.

I tried to put these variable in my Resource file (CateName, .CateName, cat.CateName).

But nothing works!

What could be wrong? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need [DisplayNameAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.displaynameattribute?view=netframework-4.7.1). You can keep one property instead of two, and decorate it with `DisplayName` attribute. You can provide resource key and resource type as parameter. For example:

```
[Display(Name = ResourceKeys.YourEmail, ResourceType = typeof(Resources.ViewModels_HomeViewModel))]
public string CateName { get; set; }
```

It will display the appropriate text according to the current culture.

Besides this, if you really want to use two different properties, then you can get the current culture value from `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name`, and add the `if` clause then render the appropriate property. For example:

```
if(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name == "en-Us")
{
 @cat.CateName
}
else
{
@cat.CateNameLocalized
}
```

Above code is just to give you idea